# Will this leak memory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

I have created a NSTimer and call it every 15 seconds. Method that I call makes web service call. In this method I write this code:

```
GetData *ws = [[GetData alloc]init];
    [ws GetSomeData:156];  
    [ws release];
```

Here I make instance to a class that call web service method, make a call and release object. Is this approach fine or bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No leak here, but if you want to do something with `ws`, don't `release` it, `autorelease` it instead.

Comment: Can you please explain why autorelease instead release?

Comment: sending `release` will put the `retainCount` to zero (in your example), and your object will be deallocated. `autoreleased` lates the deallocation of your object. So here you alloc/init it, get the data, and `release` it immediatly. Later use of `ws` could result in a crash

Comment: you should read http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml .. it gives hints and best practices. They suggest using autorelease if possible because it minimizes the chance of leaks if you forget to add releases :)

Answer (score 1):

That's the right approach. You `alloc` it, so you own it, and you must `release` it after you've done something with it.

As as side note, your method name `GetSomeData` doesn't follow Cocoa naming conventions: it should be `someData`.